# waiting for all parallel tasks and fail the completion future if any task failed

Tags: java, completable-future

I am doing concurrent processing using

```
List<CompletableFuture<String>> futures = list.stream().map(...)
                .map(id -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> fun()), pool))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Later I want to convert the `List<CompletableFuture<String>>` to a `CompletableFuture<List<String>>` and then call `join()`. I want to wait for all of them to complete; if at least one completes exceptionally then I want to throw an error.

How do I do this?

Comment: Your parentheses are mismatched.

Comment: @V J aren't you getting an exception when your job fails?

Comment: How are you converting `List<CompletableFuture<String>>` to `CompletableFuture<List<String>>`?

Comment: public <T> CompletableFuture<List<T>> allAsList(final List<CompletableFuture<T>> futures) {
        return CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[futures.size()]))
                .thenApply(ignored -> futures.stream().map(CompletableFuture::join).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }